# Reading a two columned file in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I have this two column file that looks like this:

```
9 9
1 2
3 2
```

I'm trying to read from it using `fscanf` and placing my `int * buff` as the format.

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
int num_rows = 0;
int num_columns = 2;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

int *buff = calloc(10, num_columns * sizeof(int));
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't know what to place for `fscanf(fp, %d %d\n, idk1, idk2)`

I want to place them inside `buff`, but I don't know at which locations.

```
for(i = 0; i < num_columns; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j <= num_rows; j++){
        int line = fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", &buff[num_columns], &buff[num_rows]);
        if(line == EOF){
            break;
        }
        if(num_rows % 10 == 0){
            num_rows += 10;
            buff = realloc(buff, num_rows * num_columns * sizeof(int));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm reading the values in what I think are the same locations, but I don't see the same output.

```
for(i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
  for(j = 0; j < num_columns; j++){
      printf("%d", buff[i * num_columns + j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

I see this as the output:

```
92
20
00
00
00
...
...
```

but it should just match the input file as:]

```
9 9
1 2
3 2
```

What should I place inside of `fscanf` as the locations to get the same data being printed later inside of `memarray[i * num_columns + j];`?

Comment: what is `memarray` ? Please post a [mcve] ! Not the important part COMPLETE. And please provide an exemple of expected output, I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Why not use `i` and `j`? I see some other problems: where do you set `num_rows` to something other than 0? You loop over columns primarily and then rows, but the file is read one row at a time, so those two `for` constructs should probably be switched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to store is each and every row. In your code `fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", &buff[num_columns], &buff[num_rows])` is wrong. You should use some expression of index `i` and `j` instead of using `num_rows` and `num_columns`. Basically you are over writing value at `buff[num_columns]` and `buff[num_rows]` .

You want to read your file line by line, then you can do it using single loop only. Take a loop `for(j = 0; j <= num_rows; j++)` and try storing with `fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", &buff[ num_rows*num_columns ], &buff[ num_rows * num_columns + 1 ] )`.

Also I don't know why you used `num_rows += 10;` it can disturb your index for the loop. If you want to allocate memory for 10 new rows, just give `num_rows*10` instead of `num_rows` in `realloc(buff, num_rows * num_columns * sizeof(int))`.